# Why kotlin throws "Verifier rejected class" error at creating two objects inside foreach?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have faced a really weird behavior. I have a list of type Any and I use forEach to iterate inside it. The problem is I'm creating two objects inside using a reference to the current object in the list and it just crashes.

```
projectLogEntries.forEach{
            if (it is ProjectQuery.ProjectLogEntry){
                val projectLogEntry = ProjectLogEntry(
                        createdAt = Date(),
                        remoteId =  it.id()?.toLong(),
                        remoteUserId = it.device()?.user()?.id()?.toLong(),
                        projectId = it.project()?.id()?.toLong()!!,
                        comment = "asdf"
                )

                val user =  User(
                        createdAt = Date(),
                        nameUser = it.device()?.user()?.name(),
                        remoteId = it.device()?.user()?.id()?.toLong(),
                        email = it.device()?.user()?.email() ?: "No email",
                        lastName = it.device()?.user()?.lastName() ?: "No last name"
                )
}
```

I get this error.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Verifier rejected class com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.data.respositories.ProjectRepository: void com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.data.respositories.ProjectRepository.saveProjectLogEntriesTest(java.util.List) failed to verify: void com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.data.respositories.ProjectRepository.saveProjectLogEntriesTest(java.util.List): [0x128] copy2 v24<-v6 type=Precise Low-half Constant: 0/Zero/null (declaration of 'com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.data.respositories.ProjectRepository' appears in /data/app/com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.development-g3RDRVMlGdFpZFzB8fi1lQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk)
        at com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.ui.MainProjectActivity.<init>(MainProjectActivity.kt:29)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1173)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2708)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is the code from the class `com.rhodar.mobile.codescrum.rhodarsitepacks.data.respositories.ProjectRepository`? If not, the code only triggers (directly or indirectly) the import and verification of the mentioned class where the actual problem lies.

Comment: Yeah the class is ProjectRepository :D

Comment: You could try to comment out the `val user=...` assignment. If it then happens yet, try to replace some of the expressions in parameters by plain constants and so on. If the error doesn't happen anymore, undo the changes step by step. From the error I can only guess that it has something to do with one or more of the lines containing `toLong()`.

Comment: Any chance it's finding a different version on the classpath at runtime that it was at compile time?